# Rails multi step form with Javascript – browser back button behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have 1 form that I've separated into multiple divs, each with their own Next button.

Upon clicking "Next" some javascript fires (see below) that hides the current div and unhides the next div (i.e. next step in the form). The URL is also updated with an # and the name of the step (e.g. `example.com/booking` turns into `example.com/booking#contact-info`)

```
  $('#booking-details-complete').click(function(event) {  
    $("#booking-details").css("display", "none");
    $("#contact-info").css("display", "block"); 
  });
```

The Next button code that fires this JS is:

`<%= link_to "Next", '#contact-info', :id => "booking-details-complete"%>`

The final piece of the form has a Submit button instead of a Next button, which sends one big POST request to the various models.

My problem is back button behavior: going back doesn't update the page. The URL changes correctly, but the parts of the form (i.e. the divs) don't update their show/hide state.

I'm so close to finishing this project, but just can't figure out this last piece. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you plz post your back-button-logic as well

Comment: I meant the browser's back button. I don't have a back button specifically for the form.

Comment: ok, then the problem is, that you get routed back to the initial state of the page, when getting linked back. How do you try to persist the state?

Comment: I've tried using pushState in jQuery but couldn't get it working. Other than that not persisting state. How would I save the div state for a particular URL?

Comment: as far as i know, there is no possibility to achieve your goal, if `pushState` isn't working

Comment: Hmmm... can you give a quick example of how I'd use pushState in my situation? Very possible I wasn't using it correctly (still learning Rails here...)

Comment: can you show us your effort until now?

Comment: I added a pushState call to the JS in my question. I didn't know what to put as the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

So you mean hitting "back" on your browser updates your hash in the URL properly, but your page remains static with the desired behavior being that the section you are on collapses and the previous one re-opens?

You need a hash listener, there isn't a particularly standard way of getting one I don't believe. Push and Pop history just manipulate the history stack, it won't give you what you want.

Once you have a hash listener you have to write a JS function that can set your page state based on the hash of the URL.

I've never implemented a hash listener so here's something I found that might help http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: "So you mean hitting 'back' on your browser updates your hash in the URL properly, but your page remains static". 100% correct. The desired behavior is that the divs to that part of the form will unhide, and the divs previously showing will hide themselves.

I'll look at hash listeners, hadn't heard of that until now.

Comment: It should be marked, that this plugin does not work with jQuery versions higher than 1.9.

Comment: To my knowledge, most of the time people need hash listening functionality, they're already using a front-end JS framework.. such as Marionette, Angular, Etc. These usually comes with a "router" that updates the page based on the URL hash. It woudn't hurt you to put that page state updater function in the page load as well.

Comment: Also, agreed ernd. As I mentioned, I don't know of a hash listening library that's outside of a front-end JS framework. Just something to help point him in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. To make sure I understand since I'm new...

1. Hash listener gets loaded every time the URL refreshes
2. Hash listener calls specific JS code based on the URL
3. JS updates the state of the page

Comment: I believe your understanding is correct, but I would rephrase it slightly. On page load bind to a hash listener a function that will update the state of your page based on the URL hash. A hash listener will catch anytime your hash changes. I.E mypage.com  -> mypage.com#newhash will trigger the event.